# Update trusted phone number: Cannot tap "keep using current number"

Tags: iphone, bug

I am abroad so I'm using different SIM to that associated with my Apple ID.

I'm getting an annoying badge in my iPhone settings prompting me to "Update Trusted Phoned Number".

Which takes me to the screen shown below.

Infuriatingly I am unable to tap "Keep Using +bleh".

Is this a bug? I am able to tap 'Update to +blah'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem got worse. Later I was unable to tap the screen while in settings.

Restarting the iPhone shook it loose.

I look forward to the day when restarting your device fails to fix any problems.